# Get the first double-value from string array

Tags: c#, arrays

In a method we are recieving an `Array of Strings`. Of this array we must return the first value that is a `Double`

Examples:

```
String[] myArray = {"abc", "def" , "1.0", "1.1" }; output:1.0
String[] myArray2 = {"abc", "def" , "ij" , "57.0"}; output:57.0
String[] myArray3 = {"11.1","abc", "def" , "ij" , "57.0"}; output:11.1
```

To achieve this we use the following code:

```
Double i = 0;
foreach(String s in myArray)
{
    Double.TryParse(s, out i);
    if (i > 0)
    { return i; }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a shorter way to achieve the same result?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double n;
string d = myArray.First(x => double.TryParse(x, out n))
```

You can return `n`, it will be equal to the value of first valid `double`. Btw, in your example you are cheking if `i > 0`, instead you should check the result of `TryParse` and if it's *true* return the `i`.

**Edit:** As suggested in comments the `First` method will throw an exception if there is no valid number in the array. If that is the case you can use `FirstOrDefault` and check the result:

```
string d = myArray.FirstOrDefault(x => double.TryParse(x, out n))

if(d != null) return n;
else /* return a default value */
```

Comment: It might be better to use `FirstOrDefault` just in case array does not contain any element satisfying the predicate, so it would return null instead of throwing `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Just what i was looking for! Thank you for your time to help me out!

Comment: I think, my way actually is shorter than both methods :)

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
double n;
var doubleFound = myArray.Any(x => double.TryParse(x, out n));
```

Here, it only cares about whether a double has been found, rather than returning a string back. But its purely down to what you want to do.

Just incase anyone was wondering, I tested this in LinqPad and it does return the first double found in the list.

I feel using this method or `FirstOrDefault` comes down to 2 things:

1. what do you want to do with the result of finding a value?
2. the semantics you want to use

The main difference, is one will return you what result it found in the array (`FirstOrDefault`) and the second will just say whether one was found.

Comment: But will it return the first double or just any double?

Comment: Yeah... I just thought about that, I re-read the question. I think it would probably return the last one... I think this is more to just check if the array has a double in it.

Comment: I just tested it, and it does return the first value

Comment: Altough now i'm thinking performancewise - which is better? `Any` or `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: I don't think there is going to be a lot of difference when the array is small.. but put a stopwatch around both of them a record the results